# Adding a folder from one repo to another

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have been playing around to create a `subtree`.

```
 RepoFolderSrc         RepoFolderTarget       RepoAnother
    |                        |                    |
  develop                  sfcc------------------sfcc18
    |                        |         
    |                        | 
    |-someFolder1            |
    |-someFolder2----------featureBranch
```

I want to copy the `someFolder1` and `someFolder2` from `RepoFolderSrc` to `RepoFolderTarget`. I want to retain all the history for the folder `someFolder1` and `someFolder2` when it is copied over to the `featureBranch`.

A few of the solutions I have seen requires deleting the `origin` from `RepoFolderSrc`. I should not make any changes to the `RepoFolderSrc` and I should not create any additional branch or commits on the folder.

Is there a way by which I can copy over the folder by only playing around with the `RepoFoldertarget`. I do have push and pull permissions for all repositories.